# How to test whether component contains string?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I am trying to get my head around jest. This is my test:

```
test('whether contains className', () => {

    let list = [
        {
            id: 12,
            name: 'two',
            completed: true
        }
    ];

    const wrapper = shallow(
        <Todos todos={list}>
        </Todos>
    );

    expect(wrap).toMatch(/strikethrough/);
});
```

How can I check whether a component contains a (sub)string inside the component?

Answer (score 25):

You need to get the rendered text of the current render tree with [`.text()`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/text.md) method.

```
expect(wrapper.text()).toMatch(/strikethrough/)
```

Comment: how can I check the html? I have a className value I would like to check?

Comment: Actually, this will give the html as a string. Use `console.log(wrapper.text())` and see what you are getting.

Answer (score 15):

You can also use

```
expect('Something').toContain('thing');
```

Answer (score 1):

[jest-extended package](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended) has extension [toInclude](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#toincludesubstring)

```
 expect('hello world').toInclude('ell');
  expect('hello world').not.toInclude('bob');
```